# ESRI ASCII. Latitude and longitude in a in raster

Tags: postgis, latitude-longitude, esri-ascii-raster

I've started a new project that involves a ESRI ASCII grid. As far as i know it is a map of Germany or the UK (I'm not sure which one).
This is how the header looks like:

```
NCOLS 8083
NROWS 12952
XLLCORNER -59900
YLLCORNER -58100
CELLSIZE 100
NODATA_value 0
```

I decided to use **POSTGIS** to import it into a raster table (I named the table **testraster**). The import worked smoothly, and I managed to play around with it, using some postgis functions.

For example:

```
SELECT x, y, val, ST_AsText(geom) FROM (SELECT (ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 1, true)).*
FROM testraster WHERE rid = 1) foo;
```

This select returns all the center points of my cells(cell = a value in the raster). Only the cells that have values are taken in consideration.
The very small part of the result looks like this:

```
x       y       val     st_astext
4955    353 -109    POINT(435550 -51050)
4956    353 -112    POINT(435650 -51050)
4957    353 -112    POINT(435750 -51050)
4958    353 -114    POINT(435850 -51050)
4959    353 -115    POINT(435950 -51050)
```

This takes me to my question.

How do i know the latitude and longitude of any of these points? What is the equivalent of 435940 and -51050? 
Or, a more realistic scenario: I'm in Berlin at (52.52001, 13.40495), what is the cell that i should be looking for in my raster?

Comment: Do you know what co-ord system your original ASCII grid is in?

Comment: Not really. :|. I just have the file.

Comment: After using select ST_SRID(rast) from testraster;(This returns the co-ord system) i get the result 0. I think, i have to ask the guys that gave me the file, to tell me what is the co-ord system.

Comment: Use `ST_Transform(geom, 4326)`

Comment: If i run this: `select ST_Transform(rast, 4326) from testraster ` i get **ERROR: RASTER_GDALWarp: Input raster has unknown (0) SRID**

Comment: You need to tell postgis that the data is currently in EPSG:27700. ST_SetSRID might be the right function. Once set, you can transform the ratser to EPSG:4326.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ~800 km east to west and ~1300 km north to south. This sounds like a perfect bounding box for the UK particularly if you include the islands to the north and south.  Anything but meters (say feet, km, degrees) would be unreasonable. It is a so-so fit for Germany but could work. I think we have our linear units (m) but what system? Five digits, **both** negatives in the lower left, I smell a rat.

For Germany they only approve [UTM and Gauss-Krueger](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37219/german-coordinate-system-from-lat-long). Neither makes sense due to your values and the other one I suspect it may in Germany is [EPSG:4038](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/dhdn-soldner-berlin/) but you are missing a digit before the decimal place for this to work.

So by deduction what remains is the British National Grid [EPSG:27700](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/) and those numbers look like an excellent lower left corner and this is really the only approved UK mapping grid system.

[image: could it be]

Whoever gave you this as a first mapping task (using the UK national grid in this way) may be out to get you. Just a thought. But stick your grid on this system and although not traditional it should work.

Please feedback as I am interested to see if it works, or even post your data if allowable.